# Syntax error: Problema com variável dentro do IF

Tags: mysql, funções, variáveis, if, syntax-error

Meu código:

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE FUNCTION f_desc (in_preco int)
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    DECLARE fim_preco INT;
    IF in_preco >= 100 THEN
        -- aqui
        fim_preco := format(10 * in_preco/100, 2);
    ELSEIF in_preco >= 200 THEN
        -- aqui
        fim_preco := format(20 * in_preco/100, 2);
    ELSE
        -- aqui
        fim_preco := in_preco;
    END IF;
    RETURN(fim_preco);
    END;
    //
```

Onde eu marquei fica vermelho e apresenta:

> syntax error unexpected fim_preco

Realmente não entendo o porque, já que a variável foi criada..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SET fim_preco = blablabla` no lugar de `fim_preco := blablabla`.

[**Veja aqui compilando no sqlfiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4aae80)